# Popover content is appearing in a different position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the `panel heading`,  I have inserted a link which is a `popover` and it is floated to the right (custom rule). The problem is that later the popover content is appearing at a different position.

I can add CSS rules to force popover appears next to the `badge` but I thought that this would be done automatically. So, the question is:

Am I have done something with a wrong way or because of the CSS rule `.badge-panel-r` the result I get is normal?

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

```css
.badge-panel-r {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <i class="fa fa-check space5-right"></i> result
          <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="counter"><span class="badge badge-panel-r">1</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:rgba(24, 188, 156, 0.09)">

          <p>text...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problem in your mark-up.
Use `data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="counter"` with the span.

**working snippet**

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

```css
.badge-panel-r {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <i class="fa fa-check space5-right"></i> result
          <a href="#" ><span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="counter" class="badge badge-panel-r">1</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:rgba(24, 188, 156, 0.09)">

          <p>text...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use the custom `badge-panel-r` class on the link instead. The trigger link needs to `float:right` too.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="badge-panel-r" data-placement="right" data-content="counter"><span class="badge">1</span></a>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/Y9z0qaVqS4)